# Error message while installing WGCNA package on R

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install WGCNA package on R but i get the following error:

```
> *** caught segfault *** address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped' An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ... Segmentation
> fault (core dumped) ERROR: loading failed
> * removing ‘/home/hpc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/WGCNA’  *** caught segfault *** address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'
> 
> Traceback:  1: q("no", status = status, runLast = FALSE)  2:
> do_exit(status = status)  3: do_exit_on_error()  4: errmsg("loading
> failed")  5: do_install_source(pkg_name, instdir, pkg, desc)  6:
> do_install(pkg)  7: tools:::.install_packages() An irrecoverable
> exception occurred. R is aborting now ... Segmentation fault (core
> dumped)
```

Does anyone know how can I install it?
Thanks a lot
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs during a brand new R session right? 
If so use the following code to remove the installed packages and reinstall them. I think this will solve your problem.

```
ip <- installed.packages()
pkgs.to.remove <- ip[!(ip[,"Priority"] %in% c("base", "recommended")), 1]
sapply(pkgs.to.remove, remove.packages)
sapply(pkgs.to.remove, install.packages)
```